# How to change column values according to size

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe df in a PySpark setting. I want to change a column, say it is called A, whose datatype is "`string`". I want to change its values according to their lengths. In particular, if in a row we have only a character, we want to concatenate 0 to the end. Otherwise, we take the default value. The name of the "modified" column must still be A. This is for a Jupyter Notebook using PySpark3.

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
df = df.withColumn("A", when(size(df.col("A")) == 1, concat(df.col("A"), lit("0"))).otherwise(df.col("A")))
```

I also tried the same code deleting the "`df.col`"'s.

When I run this code, the software complains saying that the syntax is invalid, but I don't see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.withColumn("temp", when(length(df.A) == 1, concat(df.A, lit("0"))).\
otherwise(df.A)).drop("A").withColumnRenamed('temp', 'A')
```

What I understood after reading your question was, you are getting one extra column A.

So you want that old column A replaced by new Column A. So I created a temp column with your required logic then dropped column A then renamed temp column to A.

Answer (score 0):

Listen here child...

1. To choose a column from a DF in *pyspark*, you must not use the "col" function, since it is a Scala/Java API. In Pyspark, the correct way is just to choose the name from the DF: df.colName.
2. To get the length of your string, use the "length" function. Size function is for iterables.

And for the grand solution... (drums drums drums)

```
 df.withColumn("A", when(length(df.A) == 1, concat(df.A, lit("0"))).otherwise(df.A))
```

Por favor!

Comment: Point 1 is not true or, at least, not precise, please check pyspark.sql.functions in order how to use col function for data frames.